# Most efficient method for converting an string object to timestamp with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a csv file that I have imported in Python's Pandas. The CSV was produced using Python already and it contains a timestamp variable. The column that I import automatically is stored as an object. In a row for example it is stored in the following manner:

```
2020-12-31 06:30:00+01:00
```

What is the most efficient method to convert it to a timestamp type that keeps the day light savings shift? I know how I can cut the string up and store it year, month, day and time slowly, but there has to be a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function:

`df['Column_Name'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column_Name'])`